# Removing Surelock and resetting a Galaxy A6 Tablet

Tags: android, adb, reset

I have recently acquired 10 Galaxy A6 tablets as a result of a child nursery closing down in a building I own. We are responsible for clearing out the space, as no one has claimed ownership. With that background information provided, I am looking to see if I can make one of these tablets operational. I attempted to access it using ADB, but USB debugging is turned off. Unfortunately, I am unable to boot into safe mode, and I do not possess the admin password for Surelock. What options are available to me? It would be a pity to dispose of these devices, even though they are somewhat dated; I would like to repurpose them if possible.

I have tried accessing it via ADB on my windows laptop and tried to boot into safemode.

Answer (score 1):

For the Galaxy A6 Tab power off then hold the power button and volume up, once you see the Loading logo lift off the power button keeping the volume up button depressed, this will get you into the safe mode, previously i tried another method. For the A4 Tab its volume down button but same process. So far 2 A4 tablets don't power on at all, one A6 has cracked screen and 2 unknown model tablets don't power on either. I have recovered 3 total tablets not sure what i will use them for but hopefully this can help someone else.